# Connect Rtabmap on Tango to ROS

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

@matlabbe, I am using Rtabmap application on Tango. I would like to connect the tablet to ROS indigo on my laptop. I followed the instructions on [this link](https://github.com/ologic/Tango/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Tango-and-ROS#install-and-configure-android-studio). But, I get some errors when I do catkin_make in **ROS Java Android workspace** section. Would you please help me how to connect it properly? Is there another way to read the data from Rtabmap app on ROS?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237459/connect-rtabmap-on-tango-to-ros/) by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

[RTAB-Map Tango app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.introlab.rtabmap&hl=en) doesn't have ROS inputs or outputs. It is a standalone version. Indeed, it would be nice to run it like a ROS node, publishing the map outside the tablet. I did not play with ROS Java yet, so not sure how integrate it.

I don't know if it could be easier to build ROS CPP as static libraries to be included in RTAB-Map app, so that no data conversion from C++ to Java would be required to publish the messages (all mapping/visualization processing is done in C++, only menus are in Java).

If you use ROS Java, you may have to convert C++ RTAB-Map/OpenCV/PCL classes to Java to publish them.

For your errors about "ROS Java Android workspace", you may post a new question about the errors (specific to ROS Java).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-06-20**:
@matlabbe  Thanks for your explanation.